# About Creating an Alt with Hopac

Tags: f#, hopac

When I use Hopac to create `Alt<unit>` with `Alt.<functions>` like always or once it would lead me to strange negative acknowledgement outcome.

But if I use `async {<expression>}` to create `Alt<unit>` then everything works as expected.

```
open Hopac
open Hopac.Core
open Hopac.Infixes
open Hopac.Extensions

let pf m (s:int) = Alt.prepareFun <| fun _ ->
    Alt.always () ^=> fun _ ->
        job { 
            printfn "starting [%s] %d" m Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
            Thread.Sleep s
            printfn "%s" m }
        |> Job.start

let delayedPrintn3 msg delayInMillis =
  Alt.prepareFun <| fun _ ->     
    async {
        printfn "starting [%s] %d" msg Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
        do! Async.Sleep delayInMillis
    }
    |> Alt.fromAsync
    |> Alt.afterFun (fun _ -> printfn "%s" msg)

let na : (string -> int -> Alt<unit>) -> string -> string -> int -> Alt<unit> = fun ff s1 s2 i ->
    Alt.withNackJob <|
        fun nack ->        
            nack
            |> Alt.afterFun (fun () ->
                  printfn "%s" s1)
            |> Job.start 
            |> Job.map (fun _ -> ff s2 i)

let na11 = na delayedPrintn3 "1 canceled!!" "na11" 3
let na22 = na delayedPrintn3 "2 canceled!!" "na22" 0

let na33 = na pf "1 canceled!!" "na33" 3
let na44 = na pf "2 canceled!!" "na44" 0

na22 <|> na11 |> run
na33 <|> na44 |> run
```

And the result are:

```
starting [na22] 18
starting [na11] 18
na22
1 canceled!!
```

and

```
starting [na33] 11
na33
```

However I want to get the same result. What's the problem when using `Alt.<function>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopac Alt's are extremely tricky and it took me a while to get them right.

When you are returning `Alt` to `prepareFun`/`prepareJob`, you're going to want to return an Alt that hasn't been committed to. In your sample for `pf` you're returning `Alt.always` which means this `Alt` is committed to always.  So when calling `na33 <|> na44 |> run` this means `na33` has already been committed to and doesn't need to run `na44`.

In contrast, example of `delayedPrintn3` is using `Async` and if you look at the reference implementation from https://github.com/Hopac/Hopac/blob/master/Docs/Alternatives.md

```
open System.Threading

let asyncAsAlt (xA: Async<'x>) : Alt<'x> = Alt.withNackJob <| fun nack ->
  let rI = IVar ()
  let tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource ()
  let dispose () =
    tokenSource.Dispose ()
    // printfn "Dispose"
  let op = async {
      try
        let! x = xA
        do rI *<= x |> start
        // do printfn "Success"
      with e ->
        do rI *<=! e |> start
        // do printfn "Failure"
    }
  Async.Start (op, cancellationToken = tokenSource.Token)
  nack
  >>- fun () ->
        tokenSource.Cancel ()
        // printfn "Cancel"
        dispose ()
  |> Job.start >>-.
  Alt.tryFinallyFun rI dispose
```

it's creating an [`IVar`](https://hopac.github.io/Hopac/Hopac.html#def:type%20Hopac.IVar) (think of them as the same as [TaskCompletionSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=netstandard-2.0)) which later will be set after the Async `op` is started. So in your example you can see both being started since their `IVar`s haven't been committed to yet.

If you're looking for a similar implementation, something like:

```
let pf2 m (s:int) = Alt.prepareJob <| fun _ ->
    let retVal = IVar<unit>()
    job { 
        printfn "starting [%s] %d" m Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
        do! timeOutMillis s
        printfn "%s" m 
        do! IVar.fill retVal ()
    }
    |> Job.start
    >>-. retVal
```

Which returns an `IVar` (which is an `Alt`) that hasn't been committed to. I had to up the sleep time to 100 to make sure Hopac didn't commit to the first one too quickly.

```
let na55 = na pf2 "1 canceled!!" "na55" 100
let na66 = na pf2 "2 canceled!!" "na66" 0
```

```
starting [na55] 9
starting [na66] 9
na66
1 canceled!!
```